# Change extension to config when using karaf feature config

Tags: osgi, karaf

I use karaf's feature config support in order to generate config files under /etc folder. The configuration in the feature file looks like:

```
<config name="com.foo.bar">
    myProperty = myValue
</config>
```

This works fine and karaf generates com.foo.bar.cfg under /etc. Now I wonder if it's possible to somehow tell karaf to use .config extension instead of .cfg. Factory configurations does not work well (they get duplicated) if .cfg extension is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  element instead of  but there will be some differences:

`<configfile finalname="/etc/myfile.cfg" override="false">URL</configfile>`

First, the content can not be inlined and has to be available through an external URL.  Second, the configuration may not be loaded when the bundle starts, because it will be handled by FileInstall asynchronously.

I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "Factory configurations does not work well (they get duplicated) if .cfg extension is used."  Have you raised a JIRA issue explaining the problem and steps to reproduce it ?  There's a released planned in a few days...

Comment: Well I am aware of configfile, but I wanted to avoid creating files per each environment. Currently we have around 30 files per environment, and about 5 or 6 environments that can have different values. There is a ticket (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-6043) that already mentioned this issue with duplicated factory configs.